# Inline code breaks link text SO Markdown renderer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-preview

*Reposted from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/11365#11365)*

The following markdown breaks:

```
![`<b>`Testing something](https://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png)
```

It renders..

```
<b>Testing something" title="" />
```

For example:

[image: <code><b></code>Testing something]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird because per the babemark test of this example:

http://is.gd/5CBft

This shouldn't be happening in markdown.pl 1.0.1 or markdown.pl 1.0.2b8. It's got to be something we're doing, somehow...

Edit: ah, I see. The sanitizer is rejecting this.

Markdown input

```
![`<b>`Testing something](http://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png)
```

Markdown output

```
<p><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png"
        alt="<code>&lt;b&gt;</code>Testing something" /></p>
```

Thus, it's not a Markdown issue, per se.. I'm not sure we really want to allow html tags of any sort inside the alt tag. So I am closing this as [status-bydesign].

Answer (score 1):

Given Jeff's explanation, it would make sense that the following Markdown *would* work:

```
![&lt;b&gt;Testing something](https://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png)
```

...and it does. ;-)

[image: <b>Testing something]